# How to tokenize printf("result is %d\n",a) ; statement by lexical analyser

Tags: compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

If the lexical anlyzer takes "result is %d\n" as one token in:
printf("result is %d\n",a); 
then how and at what stage is %d and \n are recognized as format specifier and next line respectively.

Comment: It is recognized at runtime, not during compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal string in the call to `printf` is an ordinary string literal, not different from any other string literal in your program. `printf` is an ordinary function, whose first argument is expected to be a string. Nothing requires the first argument of `printf` to be a string *literal*; it could be any expression whose value is a pointer to a string. (Although many style guides warn you against actually doing that.) So the following is perfectly legal:

```
const char* fmt = "The result is %d\n";
/* ... */

printf(fmt, a);
```

Inside string literals, escape sequences like `\n` are turned into the special characters they represent (a newline character in this case). So `"\n"` is a string literal containing a single character.

Each time `printf` is called, it scans the provided format string to identify the format conversions. Clearly, that happens at run-time, not when the program is compiled.

Having said that, since `printf` is a standard library function with well-defined behaviour, it is legal for a compiler to optimise a call to `printf` if the format argument is known at compile-time. Some compilers take advantage of this.

Answer (score 0):

The code of `printf` in `libc` "manually" parses the format string by itself, character by character. Similarly compilers do the same for type-checking the following parameters.